# How do I append sorted values in to a dictionary - Python 3.8

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, dictionary

I am new to programming and would be much appreciated if someone could direct me to the correct path from where I stuck. I have imported the values from a ***.csv*** file into a dictionary. The ***CSV*** file contains the below data (first 12 rows):

```
Project,Sub_ID,Type
2,6,Full
4,1,Full
6,6,Partial
6,7,Partial
6,8,Full
6,9,Full
6,10,Partial
6,11,Partial
7,4,Full
7,5,Full
7,6,Full
```

I was trying to create a dictionary where a key would hold a project number and then followed by its Sub_IDs and Types. Basically, I was after something similar to the following output based on the ***CSV*** data provided above.

```
{Project: 2, Sub_ID:(6), Type:(Full)
Project: 5, Sub_ID:(1), Type:(Full)
Project: 6, Sub_ID:(6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11), Type:(Partial, Partial, Full, Full, Partial, Partial)
Project: 7, Sub_ID:(4, 5, 6), Type:(Full, Full, Full)}
```

I tried to combine the data from ***.csv*** into a dictionary and loop though the dictionary to identify  which projects have multiple ***sub_ID*** and ***Type***. However, I could not able to finish the code to get the required output.  The code that I used so far is below:

```
import csv, sys
filename = 'Test Data.csv'

file_list = []
with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    try:
        for row in reader:
            file_list.append(row)
    except csv.Error as e:
        sys.exit('file %s, line %d: %s' % (filename, reader.line_num, e))

print file_list

project = []
sub_id = []
type = []
for i in file_list:
    project.append(i["Project"])
    sub_id.append(i["Sub_ID"])
    type.append(i["Type"])

for i, val in enumerate(project):
    if val == project[i-1] or val == project[i+1]  :
        print (i, ",",val," - Have multiple Sub_ID and Type")
    else:
        print (i, ",",val," - Do NOT have multiple Sub_ID and Type ")
```

Any direction or help to achieve my required output will be really helpful.

Comment: The output you provided is not valid Python, can you provide a valid Python output?

Comment: I don't have the python output. I wanted to get something similar. i.e Sub_ID and Type to be grouped to single project ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```py
import csv, sys


filename = 'Test Data.csv'

file_list = []
with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    try:
        for row in reader:
            file_list.append(row)
    except csv.Error as e:
        sys.exit('file %s, line %d: %s' % (filename, reader.line_num, e))

projects = {}
for row in file_list:
    project = int(row["Project"])
    if project not in projects:
        projects[project] = {
            "Sub_ID": [],
            "Type"  : [],
        }
    projects[project]["Sub_ID"].append(int(row["Sub_ID"]))
    projects[project]["Type"].append(row["Type"])

print(projects)
```

Output after pretty-printing it manually:

```py
{
    2: {
        "Sub_ID": [6],
        "Type": ["Full"],
    },
    4: {
        "Sub_ID": [1],
        "Type": ["Full"],
    },
    6: {
        "Sub_ID": [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11],
        "Type": ["Partial", "Partial", "Full", "Full", "Partial", "Partial"],
    },
    7: {
        "Sub_ID": [4, 5, 6],
        "Type": ["Full", "Full", "Full"],
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a dataframe (pandas)

```
import pandas as pd
filename = 'Test Data.csv'

df = pd.read_csv(filename)
```

And then use .iloc for accessing the individual rows:

```
df.iloc[0]
>>> Project       2
    Sub_ID        6
    Type       Full
    Name: 0, dtype: object
```

And if you still need the dict-style output use something like this:

```
[df.iloc[i].to_dict() for i in range(len(df))]
```

Comment: Thanks @Nikolaj Kiel. I will try